# Create Data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge the files row-wise but some of the files have different number of rows (0 as well).I am getting the following error in R:

```
fileList <- list.files(, pattern=".txt")
new_df=do.call(rbind, lapply( fileList, function(X) {
data.frame(id = basename(X), tryCatch(read.table(X), error=function(e) NULL))}
))
```

> Error in data.frame(id = basename(X), tryCatch(read.table(X), error =
>   function(e) NULL)) :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Any suggestion on how to still merge the files and create a single data frame,even though some of the files don't have any rows(how can I just ignore them) ?

Comment: Well, nesting your `read.table` call inside `data.frame` is a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.table`
Load the files with `fread`
Bind all the data.tables with `rbindlist`
I'll add code when you add a minimal reproducible example

```
library(data.table)
files = list.files(dir, pattern='.txt')
dtList = lapply(files, FUN=fread)
dt = rbindlist(dtList, use.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: I got this error :  Error in rbindlist(dtList, use.names = TRUE) : 
  Item 44 has 10 columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 11 columns. If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE.So I added argument "fill=TRUE" and it worked.